# How to return data for global use after connecting to the Bitstamp websocket?

Tags: python, websocket, cryptocurrency

I've successfully subscribed to the Bitstamp websocket and I'm now receiving live exchange data. Once I've parsed this data and assigned it to a variable (eg "asks"), how do I return this variable so that I can use it in other functions and other .py files?

Or do I have to do everything within the on_message() function? Thanks very much, code below:

```
import json
import requests
import websocket

SOCKET = "wss://ws.bitstamp.net/"

def on_open(ws):
    print("opened connection")
    subscription = {
        "event": "bts:subscribe",
        "data": {
            "channel": "order_book_btcusd"
        }
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(subscription))

def on_close(ws):
    print("closed connection")

def on_message(ws,message):
    print(message)
    data = json.loads(message)['data']
    asks = float(bitstamp_data['asks'][0][0])

def on_error(ws,error):
    print(error)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message,on_error=on_error)
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: There is no need to assign a value to a variable if you are going to return it. eg in `on_message()` just use `return float(bitstamp_data['asks'][0][0])`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried to return it as you suggested but then I'm struggling to access that data when I call `ws.run_forever()` in another .py file. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I just can't see it. Ideally what I'd like to do is connect to the websocket, and then have a variable (eg. best_bid) constantly updating with data from the exchange.

Comment: So what will need this information? It seems like the websocket calls the `on_message()` function and you get a `message` parameter that you process, but where do you want the information to go?

Comment: I have another file, `arbitrage_calculator.py`, that I'm using to calculate the premium/discounts between exchanges. At the moment I'm just using standard API calls, but would like to switch to live websocket data. So I would like to be able to call the `message` parameter into that program so I can process it in the arbitrage calculator.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some `publish/subscribe` code to the above where another program that is interested in the data signs itself up to updates.

Comment: Okay great. I'll take a look at `publish/subscribe` and see what I can find. Thanks for the help.